# how to implement extracting a user id from JWT on front end?

Tags: javascript

is there a way to simply extract the id of the user from the jwt since my jwt has the user id, I don't want it send 2 requests regarding 2 different things since the json web token has the id inside of it can i extract that info without having to send the id separately ??

```js
// get the id from Cookies 
let cookie = document.cookie;
console.log(cookie, "Raw");
cookie = cookie.split('; ');
//console.log(cookie, "Split");
let cookieObject = {};
for (let i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {
    let element = cookie[i].split('=');
    cookieObject[element[0]] = element[1];
}
//console.log(cookieObject);
let jwt = cookieObject.JWT
//console.log(jwt);
let id = `${cookieObject.id}`
//console.log(id);
```

instead of sending the id alone in another request ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking

Comment: If you're using JWTs securely, they're contained in an HTTPOnly, secure cookie, and thus cannot be accessed by JavaScript. Cache the variable server-side and client-side, then you'll only need one request to get the user id per session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWT Tokens transfered with cookies are usually not tagged with "secure", because the tokens are included in the header of each Ajax-Request to avoid CSRF (Cross-Site-Request-Forgery).
So I assume you can access the cookie.

Read the cookie:

```
const token = (document.cookie.match('(^|; )' + JWT_COOKIE_NAME + '=([^;]*)') || 0)[2] || '';
```

^^make sure to replace JWT_COOKIE_NAME with your cokies name.

Parse the cookie:

```
if (token.length > 0) {
    try {
        jwt = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
        console.log('my id: ' + jwt.id);
        // ^^ have a look at your jwt token- I only guess it's jwt.id
    } catch (e) { 
        console.log('error: ' + e);
    }
}
```

So.. what's going on here:
A JWT-token consists of 3 parts separated by a dot.
We concentrate on the middle part- the payload.

```
token.split('.')[1]
```

The payload is base64 encoded.. to get the original string we have to use

```
atob()
```

or even include some code if this function is not available (in older browsers).

Finally:

```
JSON.parse()
```

returns a js object. This object can have any properties, so I had to guess that jwt.id exists and includes your id.